# How to debug "Not including path /opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/lib in runtime library search path because it is outside target root..."

Tags: macos, opencv, rust, rust-cargo

I am unable to debug a runtime error that exhibits when running a project that includes OpenCV Rust bindings https://crates.io/crates/opencv/0.65.0

The project builds successfully:

```
[17:24:47] myuser:metadata-portal git:(main*) $ cargo build --release
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.46s
```

Running a cargo command fails:
`cargo run --release collect`

```
[2022-10-24T21:05:56Z DEBUG cargo::core::compiler] Not including path /opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/lib in runtime library search path because it is outside target root /Users/<myuser>/code/metadata-portal/target/release
Running `target/release/metadata-cli collect`
[2022-10-24T21:05:57Z ERROR] No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I have installed opencv from brew: `brew install opencv` and can confirm that `/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/lib` exists and is populated.

How might one go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

The debug output above was a red herring. The issue was actually defined by the ERROR message. A directory was missing in the structure of the project that was implementing the OpenCV bindings.